# After installing Android x86, only tGrub showing when booting

Tags: grub, boot-loader, android

I installed Android x86 5.1 RC1 in a Notebook. It works fine and I also rebooted the machine successfully. Since yesterday it doesn't boot anymore; I even  did a reinstall and deleted all partitions. Partition formatted in ext4. Installed GRUB, but not GRUB2.

When starting it's just saying `tGrub >`, but I can't even type in a command.
How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to reinstall the OS , from the installation menu:

Select *Create/modify partition*:

Create 2 partitions:

- Create a small (100m) first primary partition for grub. Set the bootable flag. Write changes.
- Create an extended (logical) partition for the rest, and install android on the 2nd. Grub will go automatically to the 1st one. Write changes.

**Edit**
[image]

Comment: How do I set the flags?

Answer (score 1):

To see the flags, when doing the partitions it will ask you for the filesystem, press <kbd>L</kbd> and then you will have the codes for the filesystem.

BIOS boot filesystem code is `EF02` then you are done with the partition.